# poEdit not creating source files

Tags: zend-framework, poedit

I am using poedit with zend_translate.
I have done everything required in zend. I have created some sample code in zend view files

```
$this->translate("Hello");
```

I have then created a new catalog in poedit.

I specified the initial settings (like base directory, translation function)

I edited php parser tab: 
a) `*.php  to *.php;*.phtml`
b) adding '-L php'

Then also its not getting any strings.
Anyone has any idea what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under catalog settings, go to "Keywords" and add "translate" — that should fix it.